# How to prevent writing before prefix in GWT valuebox

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT ValeBox with GWT Renderer to show amount with $ as prefix.

Now I want not to allow user to type any thing before dollar sign. I tried various GWT event handlers like ValueChangeHandler and some others but unable to achieve goal.

Still struggling for it. If anybody know good solution for it, please share here.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to **not** include the currency as part of the value, but next to the field.

Alternatively, you could replace the value with a numeric-only value on focus, and reformat it as a currency on blur.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of solutions:

1. Use a label before the valuebox. Label value will be $ and valuebox will contain the numeric value.
2. You can use empty text in the valuebox. Empty text will specify user to enter $ value.